# inline h3 moves ul to the right

Tags: html, css, navigation, inline

I'd like to have the navigation bar centered and the text placed to left as it is, but when I add the h3-tag the navigation bar moves to the right. How can I do this?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#toptext {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
/* Sub Menus */

.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}
/*******************************************
Style menu for larger screens

Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }
  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <h3 id="toptext">Text text text text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a href="About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="site1.html">Site1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="site2.html">Site2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*I used the navigation bar from: http://css-snippets.com/drop-down-navigation/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that is in the document flow is going to affect the position of the menu. So you would would have to take the `h3` out of the flow by positioning it absolutely.

```
#toptext {
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This has other issues but solves your initial problem.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#toptext {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  /*
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
    */
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
/* Sub Menus */

.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}
/*******************************************
Style menu for larger screens

Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }
  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <h3 id="toptext">Text text text text</h3>

  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li class="about"><a href="About">About</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="site1.html">Site1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="site2.html">Site2</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your h3 is inside the nav div. try making the h3 absolute positioned and your .nav class relatively positioned.